# How to populate dataset value in table row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I have a function of `Bind_Project_details()` which is as follows:

```
string[] Parameters = new string[3] { "@User_ID", "@PAGE_NO", "@PAGE_SIZE" };
        string[] DbTypes = new string[3] { "int","int","int" };
        string[] ParameterTypes = new string[3] { "input", "input", "input" };
        object[] values = new object[3] { iUserID, pageno, pagesize };
        string[] Lengths = new string[3] { "5","5","5" };

        P2ERefrence.Service du = new P2ERefrence.Service();

        ds = du.returnDataSet("proc", "BIND_PROJECT_GRID", Parameters, DbTypes, ParameterTypes, values, Lengths);
```

In a dataset Project, details comes from database. I want to bind these dataset values in table body as follows:

```
<table id="table1" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="" name=""></th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Project Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    .........
    .........
    .........
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: all you have to do is open a webbrowser, go to google and then search for the following terms..."asp.net gridview dataset tutorial", "asp.net databound controls tutorials"...you will get millions of search results for every audience and in every single language...give it a go

Comment: i have bind it in aspx grid, but i want to bind it in under table body  ,client not intrested in aspx grid i have fixed table head section and want data bind in table row..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you want to customise the html output from the databound server control. If that is you're case, what you can use is either a `Repeater` server control or a `ListView`. I'll explain both...

#### Using a Repeater Control

The `Repeater` provides several data templates that you can use to style your output. The ones you are interested in are:

- HeaderTemplate
- ItemTemplate
- AlternatingItemTemplate (optional)
- FooterTemplate

together you can bind the data and customise the html output. For example...

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rp" runat="server">
   <HeaderTemplate>
       <table id="table1" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Project Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
           <tbody>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <tr>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="" name=""></td>
           <td><%# Eval("User") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("Role") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("ProjectName") %></td>
       </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The `ItemTemplate` is where you define you data-binding expressions...make sure you use the correct data-binding expressions based on your own data

#### Using a ListView Control

The `ListView` control is pretty similar and works pretty much the same as the `Repeater` control. However, the `ListView` is more powerful in terms of features. Because it has A LOT of templates you can use and only gonna focus on the ones you need:

- ItemTemplate
- AlternatingItemTemplate (optional)
- LayoutTemplate

In the `LayoutTemplate` you can put whatever you want from html elements to web controls, however, it requires at least one element with the `runat=server` attribute specified and a unique ID. It uses this as a placeholder in order to data-bind (add) the data-bound items. Then you need to set the `ItemPlaceholderID` property to the id of this placeholder item. See below...

```
<asp:ListView ID="lst" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="tblBody">
   <LayoutTemplate>
       <table id="table1" class="display"  cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>GivenName</th>
                <th>DOB</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
           <tbody id="tblBody" runat="server">
           </tbody>
        </table>
   </LayoutTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <tr>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="" name=""></td>
           <td><%# Eval("GivenName") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("DOB") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("PhoneMobile") %></td>
       </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

Both the `Repeater` and the `ListView` can be data-bound by using their `DataSource` property or setting is `DataSourceID` property a valid `DataSource` control

```
lst.DataSource = dataSet1.Tables[0];
lst.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to bind DataTable to htmlTable. For that,

aspx.cs

```
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("User", Type.GetType("System.String")), new DataColumn("Role", Type.GetType("System.String")) });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "raju", "1" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "mahesh", "1" });
```

aspx

```
 <table>
            <tbody id="tbody" runat="server">
                <%foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                  { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%: item[0].ToString() %></td>
                    <td><%: item[1].ToString() %></td>
                </tr>
                <% } %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```